# For a number field $K$, the ring of integers of $K \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_p$ is $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a number field and let $p$ be an odd prime. There is a natural map
$$
\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p \to K \otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}_p,\quad \alpha \otimes n \mapsto \alpha \otimes n,
$$
and in fact the image of this map is contained in the integral closure, $A$, of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $K \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}_p$. I would like the map to give an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p \cong A$. I originally tried using Lemma 10.147.4 of the Stacks Project, but that would require $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ to be a smooth ring map, which I don't think it is (although I don't really understand what a smooth ring map is). It feels like this should be true, but I have made a few attempts to prove it and not really got anywhere.

So, to be explicit, my question is: is the natural map $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p \to K \otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}_p$ an isomorphism onto the integers of $K\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: Yes. Any element $a\in K \otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}_p - \mathcal{O}_K \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p$ is such that $\Bbb{Z}_p[a]$ is not a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module, so $a$ can't be killed by a monic $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ polynomial. Clearly to say that I am thinking to the valuations on $\prod_j K_{\mathfrak{p}_j} \cong K \otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}_p$. It may not be immediate to you, nor that $\prod_j O_{K_{\mathfrak{p}_j}} $ corresponds to $O_K \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_p$ in this isomorphism.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know the map corresponds to the canonical map $\prod_jO_{K_{\mathfrak{p}_j}}\rightarrow\prod_jK_{\mathfrak{p}_j}$ in the above notation, this reduces to noting that the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $K_{\mathfrak{p}_j}$ is $O_{K_{\mathfrak{p}_j}}$, which follows since the latter is integrally closed, hence contains the former, which is a DVR by general theory, and both have field of fractions $K_{\mathfrak{p}_j}$ since this is finite over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: @Thorgott I do not know that fact, but I do know that the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $K_{\mathfrak{p}_j}$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}_j}$, so the fact suffices to solve my problem. Could you perhaps point me to a proof of the fact or explain why it is true?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284009/why-k-otimes-mathbfq-p-prod-k-mathfrakp-i-for-number-field-k?rq=1) helps.